# Start-up folder Windows 10 Techpreview: syncthing.exe hide console on startup

Tags: windows

I have a shortcut to syncthing.exe in my Start-up folder in Windows 10. The program however starts up a console which I would like to keep hidden.

What do I change in the following image?

[image]

Comment: You can't without the source to the program

Comment: The reason why the OS won't do this is that the program could crash if it makes a system call that would fail if the window is hidden. You'll need a 3rd party program.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
  "C:\Program Files\Syncthing\syncthing.exe" -no-console
```

If you want to prevent your default browser from popping up, you can add also `-no-browser`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can `Run` it minimized.
2. You may use another terminal, [ConEmu](http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html) for example. It can start in the taskbar status area. Just change the `Target` to

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu.exe" -StartTSA -cmd "C:\Program Files\Syncthing\syncthing.exe"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can use https://github.com/cryptogeek/SyncthingHider-portable
There are other and more popular Syncthing hiders but this one is very light. Since it was made with Autohotkey you easily modify it by yourself.

Comment: Are you the author of this application?  If so we would ask you to properly disclose that you made this.  http://superuser.com/help/promotion